# Minimum Radius of a material body around a Schwarzschild Blackhole? (Topic: Circular Geodesics in Schwarzschild Spacetime)

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, geodesics

The question is to show that $r=3M$ is the minimum radius of a circular orbit for a material body in the Schwarzschild spacetime.
I did the calculations and it is coming up to $r=6M$ but as per my professor, I can show that $a/M$ is a decreasing function of $x={l^2}/{M^2}$ and take the limit to find the answer.
Does anyone know how to do this? If not this method, does anyone a different method which could be used to find the answer?

Comment: See A First Course in General Relativity by Bernard F. Schutz page 283. You write down the effective potentials for photons and for massive particles and differentiate to get the extrema.

Comment: For a Schwarzschild black hole, the [ISCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innermost_stable_circular_orbit) is at $6M=3r_s$, the photon sphere is at $3M=1.5r_s$.

Comment: What is $a$? The radius of the orbit? And $l$ the angular momentum of the orbit?

Comment: @TimRias Yes, that's correct. a is the minimum radius and L is the angular momentum

Comment: Can you explain in your question what you have tried, and how that led to the conclusion that the minimum radius is 6M?